# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in selecty statement

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I wrote query in servlet as....

```
"select Order_No from " + yard + "where Id= '" + idd + "'";
```

where yard is variable for table name and idd is variable for Id but i still get an error so please tell me my mistack and write proper query example for me...

Answer (score 3):

No space after table name

```
"select Order_No from " + yard + " where Id= '" + idd + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess idd is not string, you need not write it within ''. Your code could be like this.

```
    "select Order_No from " + yard + "where Id=" + idd + "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a space issue between yard and where clause. Try this
"select Order_No from " + yard + " where Id='" + idd + "'";